# Question about differences in standard I/O optimization for cin and cout

Tags: c++, optimization, io

As a competitive programmer, I've always used `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);` to speed up `cin` and `cout`. But I've also seen other people use optimizations like `cin.sync_with_stdio(0);` or `cout.sync_with_stdio(0);`. For example, the latter two were used in this website: https://usaco.guide/general/fast-io?lang=cpp.

I know that `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);` unsyncs `iostream`(`cin` and `cout`) from `stdio`(`scanf` and `printf`), so why would someone unsync only the input `cin` or only the output `cout` when doing competitive programming (which usually has a large amount of both input and output)?

Comment: Good on you for trying to figure out what's going on and not simply [joining the cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and drinking the Kool-Aid. Knowing how and why things work will eventually put you far ahead of most of your competition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sync_with_stdio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) is a static method, `cin.sync_with_stdio(0)` does *"exactly"* the same as `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);`.

*Not really exactly as it odr-uses `std::cin` but it is no-op.*

Answer (score 0):

Setting std::ios::sync_with_stdio(0) tells the C++ I/O streams not to bother about keeping up with the C-style I/O routines. This can increase the efficiency of your C++ I/O operations, particularly if you don't need to mix C++ streams and C-style functions.

Comment: This doesn't really address the actual question, which is about the difference between calling the function on a stream *instance* and on the class name.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35026736)